# Translation of "Get complete peace of mind"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich tue mich schwer, diese englische Phrase ins Deutsche zu übersetzen. Als temporäre Lösung hätte ich: »Ein ruhiges Gewissen haben.«
Allerdings soll das deutsche »Get complete peace of mind« ohne Kontext dastehen, was mit der gewählten Übersetzung irgendwie nicht ganz so passt.

Answer (score 2):

> Ein ruhiges Gewissen haben

That would be appropriate if the original version would be `Have complete peace of mind`.

***Get***, however, implies a change of state

> **Wieder** ein ruhiges Gewissen haben / Ein **beruhigtes** Gewissen haben

That slightly indicates, that the conscience was mollified.

> Wieder ruhig schlafen können

is quite commonly used and there is something of an exaggeration in it.

> Inneren Frieden finden

is kind of profound.

Related phrases are

> etwas [innerlich] abschließen / über etwas hinweg sein

Answer (score 1):

The translation

> ein ruhiges Gewissen haben

doesn't completely capture the original as it assumes that a troubled conscience, i.e. your wrongdoing, be the cause of your unsettled mind, while there can be numerous other reasons ( being overworked, economic hardship, emotional stress etc. ).

Better use

> inneren Frieden finden

(as suggested by @embert), though that assumes there has been an inner fight that has worn you down (in common speech though, the recipient probably wouldn't wonder ).

I'd recommend the imho most widely applicable

> die innere Mitte finden

which also conveys a meditative notion.